# Git remote: Permission to one depository denied to a previous depo owner

Tags: git, github

I committed some code to a repo some time ago, but after that I cannot make new commits to other repos.

Everytime I tried to commit, it will give me the message 
"remote: Permission to XXX/XXX.git denied to XXX(username of a previous repo I committed to".
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/XXX/XXX/': The requested URL returned error: 403"

I tried to reset SSH, tried to reset remote-v, etc... nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You are not longer allowed to push into that repository. One of the current owners must have revoked your rights. The `403 - Forbidden` error is for [permission problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).

You can check your rights by going to [github](https://github.com/) and checking on the repository. Try to edit the readme or check if it is mentioned under your Personal Settings > Repositories.

Comment: Do you mean the previous repo's owner should revoke my rights?

Comment: @YaoYang Not the previous owner, one of the current owners revoked your rights so you don't have access anymore.

Comment: I do have rights to commit to the new person's repo, it's just I can't commit to it and it is always denied by the previous repo's owner.

Comment: @YaoYang No you don't. If you had this rights you wouldn't have this problem. Does the repo show in 'Settings > Repositories'? If not you need a new permission to commit to it.